# Looking for Playwright install only on a deployed application

Tags: javascript, playwright

I have `Playwright` working fine locally.

But when the application is deployed and I try access a rest call which uses `Playwright`, getting following error:

> Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or
> updated. ║ ║ Please run the following command to download new
> browsers: ║ ║ ║ ║ npx playwright install

Why? Playwright is already installed. Is part of the dependencies in my package.json file.

What does it mean by install again? It would have been installed via `npm install` during deployment.

```
// package.json file
  "dependencies": {
    // other deps
    "playwright": "^1.36.2"
  },
```

Comment: Nope, `npx playwright install` will run a script belongs to playwright which will install the necessary browsers.

Comment: @Eldar Tried to update script to npm install && npx playwright install. Same error.

Comment: What was the output from `npx playwright install`? What is your deploy environment?